# SQL - Count values in a column using criteria and partition by

Tags: sql, datetime, count, teradata, window-functions

I have the following data set that contains an animal and its vaccine date.  I am trying to count at each record how many vaccines the pet has had in the past 90, 180, and 365 days via SQL.  I am able to figure this out in Excel.  Pasting the below table in Excel cell `A1` and placing the following formula `COUNTIFS(C:C,"<"&C2,C:C,">="&C2-90,A:A,A2)` in cell `D2`.  You can adjust the `90` to `180` and `365` respectively.

```
Animal  Visit_ID    Vaccine_Date    Count_90    Count_180   Count_365
Cat 1   7/22/2017   0   0   0
Cat 2   8/1/2017    1   1   1
Cat 3   8/14/2017   2   2   2
Cat 4   8/23/2017   3   3   3
Cat 5   9/11/2017   4   4   4
Cat 6   9/30/2017   5   5   5
Cat 7   10/11/2017  6   6   6
Cat 8   10/23/2017  6   7   7
Cat 9   10/31/2017  6   8   8
Cat 10  11/6/2017   7   9   9
Cat 11  11/17/2017  7   10  10
Cat 12  11/29/2017  7   11  11
Cat 13  12/11/2017  7   12  12
Cat 14  12/25/2017  8   13  13
Cat 15  1/2/2018    8   14  14
Cat 16  1/29/2018   7   13  15
Cat 17  2/22/2018   5   12  16
Cat 18  3/9/2018    5   13  17
Cat 19  3/21/2018   5   13  18
Cat 20  4/13/2018   4   12  19
Cat 21  5/21/2018   4   9   20
Cat 22  8/27/2018   0   4   17
Cat 23  9/18/2018   1   3   17
Cat 24  10/3/2018   2   4   17
Cat 25  12/19/2018  1   3   11
Cat 26  12/22/2018  2   4   12
Cat 27  1/6/2019    2   5   11
Cat 28  1/30/2019   3   6   11
Cat 29  3/10/2019   4   6   10
Cat 30  3/26/2019   3   6   10
Cat 31  4/17/2019   3   6   10
Cat 32  5/13/2019   3   7   11
Cat 33  5/18/2019   4   8   12
Cat 34  5/25/2019   5   9   12
Cat 35  6/17/2019   5   10  13
Cat 36  7/2/2019    5   9   14
Cat 37  7/12/2019   6   9   15
Cat 38  8/2/2019    6   9   16
Cat 39  8/15/2019   6   10  17
Cat 40  8/27/2019   5   11  18
Cat 41  9/9/2019    6   11  18
Cat 42  9/17/2019   6   12  19
Cat 43  9/26/2019   7   12  19
Cat 44  10/9/2019   7   13  19
Cat 45  10/19/2019  7   13  20
Cat 46  11/12/2019  7   13  21
Cat 47  11/15/2019  7   13  22
Cat 48  11/26/2019  7   13  23
Cat 49  12/20/2019  6   13  23
Cat 50  12/31/2019  6   13  23
Cat 51  2/14/2020   3   11  22
Cat 52  3/8/2020    3   10  23
Cat 53  4/6/2020    2   9   22
Cat 54  5/5/2020    3   8   22
Cat 55  5/23/2020   3   7   21
Cat 56  6/18/2020   3   6   20
Cat 57  6/30/2020   4   6   21
Cat 58  7/16/2020   4   7   20
Cat 59  7/22/2020   5   8   21
Dog 1   3/8/2018 0:00   0   0   0
Dog 2   4/18/2019 0:00  0   0   0
Dog 3   7/1/2019 0:00   1   1   1
Dog 4   12/12/2019 0:00 0   1   2
Dog 5   12/23/2019 0:00 1   2   3
```

However, when I try to accomplish this via SQL with the following code, it is just looking at the previous row and adding.  It doesn't seem to count backwards at each vaccine date as the Excel formula above does and I'm not sure how to integrate a window function to count vaccine dates that happened in the past based on 90,180,365 intervals while being partitioned by an animal.

```
select
qry3.Animal
,qry3.Vaccine_Date
,(case when qry3.Count_90 = 0 then 0 else row_number() over (partition by qry3.Animal, qry3.Count_90_2 order by qry3.animal_rank) - 1 end) as Admit_90
,(case when qry3.Count_180 = 0 then 0 else row_number() over (partition by qry3.Animal, qry3.Count_180_2 order by qry3.animal_rank) - 1 end) as Admit_180
,(case when qry3.Count_365 = 0 then 0 else row_number() over (partition by qry3.Animal, qry3.Count_365_2 order by qry3.animal_rank) - 1 end) as Admit_365 
from

(
select
qry2.Animal
,qry2.Vaccine_Date
,qry2.animal_rank
,qry2.Count_90
,qry2.Count_180
,qry2.Count_365
,sum(case when qry2.Count_90 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by qry2.Animal order by qry2.animal_rank rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Count_90_2
,sum(case when qry2.Count_180 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by qry2.Animal order by qry2.animal_rank rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Count_180_2
,sum(case when qry2.Count_365 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by qry2.Animal order by qry2.animal_rank rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Count_365_2

from
(
select
qry1.Animal
,qry1.Vaccine_Date
,qry1.animal_Rank
,case when qry1.Vaccine_Date-qry1.Previous_Vaccine_Date < 90 then 1 else 0 end as Count_90
,case when qry1.Vaccine_Date-qry1.Previous_Vaccine_Date < 180 then 1 else 0 end as Count_180
,case when qry1.Vaccine_Date-qry1.Previous_Vaccine_Date < 365 then 1 else 0 end as Count_365

from
(
select
a.Animal
,a.Vaccine_Date
,b.Vaccine_Date as Previous_Vaccine_Date
,row_number() over (partition by null order by A.Animal,a.Vaccine_Date) as animal_Rank

from Animal_Vaccine a
left join Animal_Vaccine b on a.Visit_ID = b.Visit_ID - 1

) as qry1
) as qry2
) as qry3
```

Here are the results from the SQL(again I'm trying to mimic the excel formula found at the top):

```
Animal  Vaccine_Date    Count_90    Count_180   Count_365
Cat 7/22/2017 0:00  0   0   0
Cat 8/1/2017 0:00   1   1   1
Cat 8/14/2017 0:00  2   2   2
Cat 8/23/2017 0:00  3   3   3
Cat 9/11/2017 0:00  4   4   4
Cat 9/30/2017 0:00  5   5   5
Cat 10/11/2017 0:00 6   6   6
Cat 10/23/2017 0:00 7   7   7
Cat 10/31/2017 0:00 8   8   8
Cat 11/6/2017 0:00  9   9   9
Cat 11/17/2017 0:00 10  10  10
Cat 11/29/2017 0:00 11  11  11
Cat 12/11/2017 0:00 12  12  12
Cat 12/25/2017 0:00 13  13  13
Cat 1/2/2018 0:00   14  14  14
Cat 1/29/2018 0:00  15  15  15
Cat 2/22/2018 0:00  16  16  16
Cat 3/9/2018 0:00   17  17  17
Cat 3/21/2018 0:00  18  18  18
Cat 4/13/2018 0:00  19  19  19
Cat 5/21/2018 0:00  20  20  20
Cat 8/27/2018 0:00  21  21  21
Cat 9/18/2018 0:00  22  22  22
Cat 10/3/2018 0:00  23  23  23
Cat 12/19/2018 0:00 24  24  24
Cat 12/22/2018 0:00 25  25  25
Cat 1/6/2019 0:00   26  26  26
Cat 1/30/2019 0:00  27  27  27
Cat 3/10/2019 0:00  28  28  28
Cat 3/26/2019 0:00  29  29  29
Cat 4/17/2019 0:00  30  30  30
Cat 5/13/2019 0:00  31  31  31
Cat 5/18/2019 0:00  32  32  32
Cat 5/25/2019 0:00  33  33  33
Cat 6/17/2019 0:00  34  34  34
Cat 7/2/2019 0:00   35  35  35
Cat 7/12/2019 0:00  36  36  36
Cat 8/2/2019 0:00   37  37  37
Cat 8/15/2019 0:00  38  38  38
Cat 8/27/2019 0:00  39  39  39
Cat 9/9/2019 0:00   40  40  40
Cat 9/17/2019 0:00  41  41  41
Cat 9/26/2019 0:00  42  42  42
Cat 10/9/2019 0:00  43  43  43
Cat 10/19/2019 0:00 44  44  44
Cat 11/12/2019 0:00 45  45  45
Cat 11/15/2019 0:00 46  46  46
Cat 11/26/2019 0:00 47  47  47
Cat 12/20/2019 0:00 48  48  48
Cat 12/31/2019 0:00 49  49  49
Cat 2/14/2020 0:00  50  50  50
Cat 3/8/2020 0:00   51  51  51
Cat 4/6/2020 0:00   52  52  52
Cat 5/5/2020 0:00   53  53  53
Cat 5/23/2020 0:00  54  54  54
Cat 6/18/2020 0:00  55  55  55
Cat 6/30/2020 0:00  56  56  56
Cat 7/16/2020 0:00  57  57  57
Cat 7/22/2020 0:00  58  58  58
Dog 3/8/2018 0:00   0   0   0
Dog 4/18/2019 0:00  0   0   0
Dog 7/1/2019 0:00   1   1   1
Dog 12/12/2019 0:00 0   2   2
Dog 12/23/2019 0:00 1   3   3
```

Comment: What's your Teradata release?

Comment: Look like I'm on Version 15.10

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by joining back to the table it self on animal and between vaccine dates and then counting distinct visit_id.  I was totally over complicating it, but would be open to a window function, as I enjoy them!

```
select
a.Animal
,a.Vaccine_Date
,a.visit_id
,count(distinct b.visit_id) - 1 as Count_90 --minus 1 so it as to not count itself
,count(distinct c.visit_id) - 1 as Count_180 --minus 1 so it as to not count itself
,count(distinct d.visit_id) - 1 as Count_365 --minus 1 so it as to not count itself

from Animal_Vaccine a
left join Animal_Vaccine b on a.Animal = b.Animal and b.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 90 and a.Vaccine_Date
left join Animal_Vaccine c on a.Animal = c.Animal and c.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 180 and a.Vaccine_Date
left join Animal_Vaccine d on a.Animal = d.Animal and d.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 365 and a.Vaccine_Date

group by 1,2,3
;
```

Comment: There seems to be a low number of rows per `Animal`, otherwise this triple product join will consume a huge amount of CPU :-)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of rows per value is quite low, your approach will be ok. But if the number row rows per value increases, CPU will explode and your DBA will phone you :-)

But your query query can be simplified to a single product join instead of three, assuming that animal/visit_id is unique:

```
select
   a.Animal
  ,a.Vaccine_Date
  ,a.visit_id
  ,count(case when b.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 90 and a.Vaccine_Date then b.visit_id end)  as Count_90
  ,count(case when b.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 180 and a.Vaccine_Date then b.visit_id end) as Count_180
  ,count(b.visit_id) as Count_365
from vt a
left join vt b
  on a.Animal = b.Animal
 and b.Vaccine_date between a.Vaccine_Date - 365 and a.Vaccine_Date - 1 -- don't include current row
group by 1,2,3
```

Performance can be improved if `Animal` is the Primary Index (otherwise creating a Volatile Table with that index is also possible).

Depending on the number of rows per animal and the range of dates it might be better to simply create the missing dates using EXPAND, then ROWS can be used instead of RANGE:

```
select animal, Visit_ID, Vaccine_date
   -- EXPAND ON returned one row per day with repeated data, the CASE effectily NULLs the added rows
  ,count(case when valid_from = Vaccine_date then 1 end) over (partition by animal order by Vaccine_date rows between 90 preceding and 1 preceding)
  ,count(case when valid_from = Vaccine_date then 1 end) over (partition by animal order by Vaccine_date rows between 180 preceding and 1 preceding)
  ,count(case when valid_from = Vaccine_date then 1 end) over (partition by animal order by Vaccine_date rows between 365 preceding and 1 preceding)
from
 ( -- create the missing dates to get 1 row per animal/day
   select animal, Visit_ID, begin(pd) as Vaccine_date, valid_from
   from
    ( 
      select animal, Visit_ID
        ,cast(Vaccine_date as date) as valid_from -- seems to be a Timestamp
        -- get the next row's Vaccine_date for EXPAND ON in following step
/*      -- LAG/LEAD not supported in TD 15.10
        ,lead(Vaccine_date,1,Vaccine_date+1)
         over (partition by animal
               order by Vaccine_date) as valid_to 
 */     -- workaround for LEAD
        ,coalesce(min(Vaccine_date)
                  over (partition by animal
                        order by Vaccine_date
                        rows between 1 following and 1 following)
                 ,Vaccine_date +1) as valid_to -- replace the last row's NULL with a valid end date 
      from vt
    ) as prepare_data
   expand on period(valid_from, valid_to) as pd
 )  as expand_data
-- now remove the added dates again
qualify valid_from = Vaccine_date
```

This assumes that there's only one row per day per animal, otherwise you'll get an error message during EXPAND ON. Then data has to be aggregated in the prepare step.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Teradata does not support range window frames, so you can't do what you want with window functions. The solution suggested by dnoeth using one left join and conditional aggregation provides a valid workaround.

I wonder, however, whether a couple of correlated subqueries would perform better, since it avoids the need for outer aggregation at all:

```
select
    v.*,
    (select count(*) from vt v1 where v1.animal = v.animal and v1.vaccine_date >= v.vaccine_date -  90 and v1.vaccine_date < v.vaccine_date) count_90,
    (select count(*) from vt v1 where v1.animal = v.animal and v1.vaccine_date >= v.vaccine_date - 180 and v1.vaccine_date < v.vaccine_date) count_180,
    (select count(*) from vt v1 where v1.animal = v.animal and v1.vaccine_date >= v.vaccine_date - 365 and v1.vaccine_date < v.vaccine_date) count_365
from vt v
```

For this query, make sure that you have an index on `(animal, vaccine_date)`.

Comment: Should be better than those three joins plus distinct, but as Teradata is a massive parallel system those Scalar Correlated Subqueries with non-equality are also hard to optimize. That index will not help unless it's a Materialized View, and he will probably not be allowed to create indexes on that table.